# What does happens when you type set in terminal

Tags: 10.04, command-line

I wanted to see if `set` does mean something and I typed it in terminal and after that I got huge code which doesn't even fit in my screen. So I wanted to ask what does it do? I hope I didn't broke something in Ubuntu after typing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't break anything - don't worry.  Typing 'set' just displays all of the shell variables and functions.  set is used to set the variables and functions that are available and all you did was essentially asked to see what was currently set.